# Weird behavior of check boxes in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a web app to customize a horse avatar, so i have a canvas where the part of the horse are loaded, marking of the face is one of the part that can selected via a checkbox then loaded inside the canvas. user is allowed to select multiple checkboxes therefore load multiple marking faces.

When i have multiple checkboxes checked, lets say i have checked in order checkbox 1 and 2 and 3, the images load inside the canvas just fine but when i uncheck checkbox 1, instead of removing the image related to checkbox 1 it removes the image related to the last one i clicked which is check box 3. i don't know if i explained the issue well or not but here is a short video that shows the problem : https://youtu.be/_gPSCuJusqc

and here is the code i wrote for all checkboxes in javascript :

```
           document.getElementById('markingBtn15').addEventListener('change', function() {
         
        if (k15.checked==true){
            matrixIndex=14;
            markingMatrix[matrixIndex][0].src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0591/0741/0083/files/lowresmarking15.png"
        markingMatrix[matrixIndex][0].onload = function(){
            
            buildhorse();
        }
        }else{
            markingMatrix[matrixIndex][0].src="";
            
            buildhorse();
        
        }
        });
```

Comment: _"here is a short video that shows the problem"_ - [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> Add a [mcve] that shows the actual (faulty) behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to figure out exactly what you are trying to do based on the small amount of code given, but if you are going to have a bunch of checkboxes, you probably want to have some global array of boolean values to keep track of which box is checked and which isn't.

```
var boxValues = [true, false, false, false, false];
```

and then a matching set of images

```
var images = [image1, image2, image3, image4, image5];
```

and then each time you click on a box, map it to an index value and use that index value to updating both boxValues and images and refresh your screen so everything stays in sync.

does that help at all?